# Android Background image size

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar

I am creating a background image for an android application, but if I take the screen size for the image, the image is distorted by the size of the action bar. What size must have the image for different densities without the action bar?

thanks

Comment: http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#top check this